# how to tell f2py module to look in current directory for shared object dependency

Tags: python, linux, shared-libraries, f2py

```
system: lubuntu 18.04, running in VirtualBox
```

suppose I have the following directory of sources (code for these at the bottom):

```
/f2pyproject/
  - lib.f
  - prog.f
  - f2pyprog.f
  - test.py
```

`prog.f` is a simple fortran executable that will call a subroutine in the shared object compiled from `lib.f`.

To achieve this:

```
>>> gfortran -shared lib.f -o lib.so
>>> gfortran prog.f lib.so -o prog.exe -Wl,-rpath=.
>>> ./prog.exe
    hello world
```

where the `-Wl,-rpath=.` option tells prog.exe to look in the current directory for its linked shared object so that I don't have worry about `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

now I want to call this same linked subroutine in python so I compile f2pyprog.f with an f2py call:

```
>>> python3 -m numpy.f2py -c f2pyprog.f lib.so -m prog
```

Now in this case, `prog.cpython-blah-blah.so` is a shared object, not an executable, so what I don't know is, how do call this workflow without having to worry about LD_LIBRARY_PATH but keeping the shared object in the same directory as the f2py compiled library.

calling test.py fails:

```
>>> python3 test.py  (fails with ImportError, cannot open shared object file)
```

setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH first succeeds:

```
>>> export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=`pwd`
>>> python3 test.py
    hello world
```

#### The Main Question:

Is it possible to build this (or any) f2py extension with a shared object linked in the current directory using something like the -rpath linker option and not having to worry about the `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable?

## Sources:

lib.f:

```
  subroutine helloworld()
      print*, "hello world"
  return
  end subroutine
```

prog.f:

```
  program helloworldprog
    call helloworld()
  end program helloworldprog
```

f2pyprog.f:

```
  subroutine pyhelloworld()
    call helloworld()
  return
  end subroutine
```

test.py

```
import os
from os import path
# has no effect, presumably because this needs to be set before python starts
os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH'] = path.abspath(path.dirname(__file__))  

import prog
prog.pyhelloworld()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. set env variable `export LDFLAGS=-Wl,-rpath=.`
2. set env variable `export NPY_DISTUTILS_APPEND_FLAGS=1`
3. upgrade `numpy` to `1.16.0` or greater

Although you cannot pass linker flags from the command line in f2py, it will read the `LDFLAGS` environment variable.  However, the default [behavior for numpy is to *overwrite* the flags](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/7427) used in compiling rather than appending them which will cause failure in compiling if the required flags are not present in `LDFLAGS`.  [Support was added in `numpy` version `1.16.0`](https://github.com/rgommers/numpy/commit/6302450381522bfa29571d1f3f99aec7df876c69) for optionally appending these linker flags by setting the environment variable `NPY_DISTUTILS_APPEND_FLAGS=1`

```
>>> unset LD_LIBRARY_FLAGS   # just in case was set before
>>> export LDFLAGS=-Wl,-rpath=.
>>> export NPY_DISTUTILS_APPEND_FLAGS=1
>>> python3 -m numpy.f2py -c progpy.f lib.so -m prog
>>> python3 test.py
    hello world
```