# How to pass linker flags to f2py?

Tags: python, fortran, lapack, f2py

I am trying to wrap a set of Fortran files to Python using f2py. I am using the gfortran compiler via mingw64. The sources I am trying to wrap contain Lapack functions, so I built Lapack and Blas following the "Easy windows build" instructions on this webpage: https://icl.cs.utk.edu/lapack-for-windows/lapack/#build. I am now able to compile my source file by running

```
gfortran foo.F90 -ffree-line-length-512 -llapack -lblas -fdec-math -Wl,-allow-multiple-definition
```

As you can see I need to pass a set of options, which are not really all that relevant here except for the last one `-Wl,-allow-multiple-definition`. I have found that if I do not include this option the file won't compile and I get a whole set of errors all ending with `` multiple definition of `_gfortran[...] `` where `[...]` contains some extra string, like for example `_st_open'`. Perhaps that last option is a bit of a hack, but at least the file compiles without issues.

However I do not know how to pass this linker option to f2py. Currently I run,

```
python -m numpy.f2py -llapack -lblas   -c foo.F90 
 --fcompiler=gnu95 --compiler=mingw32 --f90flags="-ffree-line-length-512 -fdec-math -Wl,-allow-multiple-definition" -m foo_py
```

But this doesn't seem to do anything, I just get the same multiple definition error as if the linker flag wasn't included. So what syntax should I use?

Thanks!

EDIT: After some extensive googling it seems like f2py contains no option to pass linker flags to the compiler. So now I am wondering if there is some way to force the `allow-multiple-definition` option on the compiler globally.

I think the error itself must somehow originate in how I have built LAPACK and BLAS. Similar errors have been reported before, see https://icl.cs.utk.edu/lapack-forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=5315, but seemingly only in the built process and not during a fortran compile. Would there be alternative ways to build LAPACK such that I can easily incorporate it with gfortran?

Answer (score 1):

Did you have a look at this: [how to tell f2py module to look in current directory for shared object dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54201961/how-to-tell-f2py-module-to-look-in-current-directory-for-shared-object-dependenc)

There the following is suggested:

1. set env variable `export LDFLAGS=-Wl,-rpath=.`
2. set env variable `export NPY_DISTUTILS_APPEND_FLAGS=1`
3. upgrade numpy to 1.16.0 or greater

Comment: Thanks! LDFLAGS=-lgomp solved my problem of getting "ImportError: ...linux.gnu.so: undefined symbol: GOMP_parallel" after seemingly successful compilation.